# Parsing a number using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I got in my site several amounts of money displayed like this: $5,000
I want to sum all of them and to check some variables. How can I parse and get the number 5000 and use it as a number (summing up, multiplying etc) using Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`storeEval`](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#store-commands-and-selenium-variables) and parse the string into the `Number` using javascript:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>Number('$5,000'.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));</td>
    <td>amount</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${amount}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```